# Request help on a regex

Tags: regex

What i current got actually: `\/\*global\*\/([\/\*\+])`

I would like to match only: `/*global*//*+`

https://regex101.com/r/Jub37K/1/

Comment: Repeat the character class, and you can omit the group `\/\*global\*\/[\/*+]+` https://regex101.com/r/RKylf3/1

Comment: In most regex dialects, you don't need to backslash the slashes, either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can omit the capture group and repeat the character class 1 or more times to not match the other 2 string.

Note that you don't have to escape `*` and `+`.

```
\/\*global\*\/[\/*+]+
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Uxnkdj/1)

Depending on the delimiters of the pattern, you might also shorten it to

```
/\*global\*/[/*+]+
```